# Anybody using SQL Source Control from Red Gate

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008, redgate

We have been looking into possible solutions for our SQL Source control.  I just came across Red Gates SQL Source control and wondered if anyone has implemented it? I am going to download the trial and give it a shot, but just wanted to see if others have real experience.

As always greatly appreciate the input

--S

Comment: I'd love the feedback as well - we're sorely in need of some source control for out SQL Servers, and despite our best effort, Visual Studio Database isn't cutting it.

Comment: I have downloaded a trial version. It's a pity that it does not support getting older revisions from the repository, only the latest. Actually I'm not quite sure what is the difference between SQL Source Control and SQL Compare?

Comment: Oh so you have to go to the actual SVN repository folder to view the historical "Older" revisions?

Comment: It says here:

http://www.red-gate.com/supportcenter/Content.aspx?p=SQL%20Source%20Control&c=SQL_Source_Control/help/1.0/SSC_Getting_Latest_Version.htm&toc=SQL_Source_Control/help/1.0/toc905718.htm

Getting previous versions
SQL Source Control does not currently support getting specific versions of an object within SQL Server Management Studio.

To get a specific version or revision of a database, use your source control system to create a local version of the scripts folder representing that revision, and synchronize it with the database using SQL Compare

Comment: It will soon be possible to get older revisions directly from SQL Source Control, although this will still require a license of SQL Compare Pro, which is why we highly recommend purchasing the full SQL Developer Bundle. David Atkinson, Red Gate Software.

Comment: For info on integrating SQL source control and deployment into CI workflow: - http://www.troyhunt.com/2010/07/rocking-your-sql-source-control-world.html - http://www.troyhunt.com/2011/02/automated-database-releases-with.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I use SQL Compare for generating scripts when going from dev -> test -> production and it saves me tons of time.

For source control though, we use SVN and ScriptDB (http://scriptdb.codeplex.com/) though. I mainly use source control of SQL scripts for keeping track of changes. I think that rolling back a version of the database seldomly (if ever) works since data may have changed when making structure changes.

This works fine for a few of our current projects (largest is 200 tables and 2000 sprocs). The main reason for doing this though is cost since not all team members have to buy SQL Compare (I avoid adding dependencies to commercial projects unless really needed).

Comment: I guess you could always use Red-Gate SQL Data Compare for reference tables, it's a pain either way though.

Comment: As You say, it works pretty good for reference tables, but if You are modifying the structure of a entity table (e.g. Customers) or alter associations, then You are in trouble when it comes to recreation of an old version of the database.

Comment: We hope to support Static Data from the SQL Source Control UI in v2.0. We recognise that although it is possible to use SQL Data Compare, SSMS integration will greatly improve the user experience.
David Atkinson, Red Gate Software.

Comment: SQL Source Control 2 now supports static data. We'd appreciate it if you could take a look and let us know if it now meets your needs.

Answer (score 26):

**I have updated my original post below to reflect changes in the latest versions of SQL Source Control (3.0) and SQL Compare (10.1).**

Since this question was asked over a year ago, my response may not be that helpful to you, but for others who may currently be evaluating SSC, I thought I would throw in my two cents.  We just started using SQL Source Control (SSC) and overall I am fairly satisfied with it so far.  It does have some quirks though, especially if you are working in a shared database environment (as opposed to every developer working locally) and particularly working in a legacy environment where objects in the same database are divided haphazardly between development teams.

To give a brief overview of how we are using the product in our organization, we are working in a shared environment where we all make changes to the same development database, so we attached the shared database to the source control repository.  Each developer is responsible for making changes to the objects in the database through SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), and when they are finished, they can commit their changes to source control.  When we are ready to deploy to staging, the build master (me) merges the development branch of the database code to the main (staging) branch and then runs SQL Compare using the main branch repository version of the database as the source and the live staging database as the target, and SQL Compare generates the necessary scripts to deploy the changes made to the staging environment. Staging to production deployments works in similar fashion. One other important point to note is that, given the fact that we are sharing the same database with other development teams, we use a built in feature of SSC that allows you to create filters on database objects by name, type, etc.  We manually set up filters on our specific team's objects, excluding all other objects, so that we don't accidentally commit other development team's changes when we do our deployments.

So in general it's a fairly simple product to set up and use and it's really nice because you're always working with live objects in SSMS, as opposed to disconnected script files stored in a separate source repository that run the risk of getting out of sync.  It's also nice because SQL Compare generates the deployment scripts for you so you don't have to worry about introducing errors as you would if you were creating the scripts on your own.  And as SQL Compare is a very mature and stable product, you can feel pretty confident that it's going to create the proper scripts for you.

With that being said, however, here are some of the quirks that I have run into so far:

- SSC is pretty chatty out of the box in terms of communicating with the db server in order to keep track of database items that are out of sync with the source control repository.  It polls every few milliseconds and if you add in multiple developers all working against the same database using SSC, you can imagine that our dba's weren't very happy.  Fortunately, you can easily reduce your polling frequency to something more acceptable, although at the cost of sacrificing responsive visual notifications of when objects have been changed.
- Using the object filtering feature, you can't easily tell from looking at objects in SSMS which objects are included in your filter.  So you don’t know for sure if an object is under source control, unlike in Visual Studio, where icons are used to indicate source controlled objects.
- The object filtering GUI is very clunky.  Due to the fact that we are working in a legacy database environment, there is currently not a clear separation between the objects that our team owns and those owned by other teams, so in order to prevent us from accidentally committing/deploying other teams’ changes, we have set up a filtering scheme to explicitly include each specific object that we own.  As you can imagine, this becomes quite cumbersome, and as the GUI to edit the filters is set up to enter one object at a time, it could become quite painful, especially trying to set up your environment for the first time (I ended up writing an application to do this).  Going forward, we are creating a new schema for our application to better facilitate object filtering (besides being a better practice anyway).
- Using the shared database model, developers are allowed to commit any pending changes to a source controlled database, even if the changes are not theirs.  SSC does give you a warning if you try to check in a bunch of changes that these changes might not be yours, but other than that you’re on your own.  I actually find this to be one of SSC’s most dangerous “quirks”.
- SQL Compare can’t currently share the object filters created by SSC, so you would have to manually create a matching filter in SQL Compare, so there is a danger that these could get out of sync.  I just ended up cut-and-pasting the filters from the underlying SSC filter file into the SQL Compare project filter to avoid dealing with the clunky object filtering GUI.  I believe that the next version of SQL Compare will allow it to share filters with SSC, so at least this problem is only a short term one. **(NOTE: This issue has been resolved in the latest version of SQL Compare.  SQL Compare can now use the object filters created by SSC.)**
- SQL Compare also can’t compare against a SSC database repository when launched directly.  It has to be launched from within SSMS.  I believe that the next version of SQL Compare will provide this functionality, so again it’s another short term problem. **(NOTE: This issue has been resolved in the latest version of SQL Compare.)**
- Sometimes SQL Compare isn’t able to create the proper scripts to get the target database from one state to another, usually in the case where you are updating the schema of existing tables that aren’t empty, so you currently have to write manual scripts and manage the process yourself.  Fortunately, this will be addressed through “migration scripts” in the next release of SSC, and from looking at the early release version of the product, it appears that the implementation of this new feature was well thought out and designed. **(NOTE:  Migration scripts functionality has been officially released.  However, it does not currently support branching. If you want to use migration scripts, you will need to run sql compare against your original development code branch... the one where you checked in your changes... which is pretty clunky and has forced me to modify my build process in a less than ideal way in order to work around this limitation. Hopefully this will be addressed in a future release.)**

Overall, I am pretty happy with the product and with Redgate’s responsiveness to user feedback and the direction that the product is taking. The product is very easy to use and well designed, and I feel that in the next release or two the product will probably give us most, if not all, of what we need.

Comment: Nice detailed answer. We are currently evaluating the tool. What about the migration script and branching, does it has changed on last version?

Comment: Actually, I guess I should have gone back to update my answer. I ended up having so many issues with the product and spent so much time having to babysit it and work through the kinks that I no longer recommend it. Currently we are using Fluent Migrator and I am very satisfied with it. Essentially everything is written as a migration script, and your application can be configured to upgrade to the latest version automatically, a concept that I believe was pioneered in Ruby on Rails. Scripts should be checked into source control, so I believe that could take care of branching.

Answer (score 3):

We performed an extensive evaluation of Red Gate's product and found a few major flaws. If you want to look at who changed an object, you can't do it **without** SysAdmin privileges. The product needs to look at the trace on your server, which requires those rights. I'm on a 5+ person team, and not knowing who had pending changes is what will stop us from using the product.

Comment: If i understand correctly, your developers all access and deploy things directly to production? Or they don't even have SA privs on their dev box? Either way I think that's probably a near edge case as far as usages. Normally developers all have SA on their own box, occasionally/often have SA access on the QA box, and usually only 1 person or a few DBA have access to prod, in which case you always know who changed prod. my 2 cents.

Answer (score 1):

I just started working for a new company and they use Redgate SQL Source Control for all their projects, amonst them a large and complex one. It does the job well in tandem with TFS. The only drawback from my point of view is that the SQL Server Management Studio integration is highly unstable. Frequent crashes of SQL Server Management Studio happen when the tools are installed.